# Walmart does not allow chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am learning python, I have done some bots (nothing special), I am trying to create a new one on walmart, but when I launch chromedriver, walmart site ask me for solve a captcha, this is not a problem, because I can solve it manually.
The problem is that everytime I solve the captcha, the captcha appears again. My bot requires that I log in in walmart site, so I tested google chrome (not chromedriver) and I can login without any problem. I thought could be my ip or something else, but after some tests I realized that walmart block the log in process if I use chromedriver.
Any ideas?
thanks!

Comment: 1. always when you add question add your code because otherwise it is hard to answer your question.
2. Try to change headers in driver

Comment: Selenium uses JavaScript to control web browser and some portals can detect this JavaScript code and block access. On Stackoverflow you could find questions/answers which describe this problem and show how to compile Selenium with different names for variables in JavaScript code used by Selenium - and sometimes it can help.

Comment: did you test `Selenium` with `Firefox` or (Microsoft) `Edge`?

Comment: Yes, same error using Firefox (driver) and Microsoft edge (driver).  =(